# Forcing routes to visit closest facility in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

My dataset contains three parts: A) Incident location B) AED locations C) locations of available "first responders"(don't think of these like an ambulance or a fire department, but rather normal civilians)

Calculating the shortest path from C to A or C to B is doable with the Network Analyst tools, but is there a way for me to calculate two routes for each person in C? I.e. I'd like to have both a direct route, C to A as well as the route via the AED, C -> B -> A, where B in this case is the "closest facility"(closest AED) for the individual C.

I tried to work with barriers with negative value, but that didn't help much. Any pointers on how to create the two routes?

Answer (score 1):

Using [VRP solver](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000004v000000) will help you solving this problem. The Closest Facility solver will only let you define two input point classes (Facilities and Incidents), so there is no way to define your first responders (C class).

Check the VRP help page and try to figure out how you can define your classes based on what VRP can offer.

You can of course use Route solver to define your input stops and force the route go in a certain sequence (facilities >> AED >> incidents) which will be just three input stops in the Route layer).